# Error with my React Application - 'A valid React element (or null) must be returned'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 2 React Components which are below.  When I try to load it in Internet Explorer 9 I get the following error:
[image: IE Error]

```
// App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import Main from './Main';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Main />
  </div>
);

export default App;

// Main.jsx
import React from 'react';

const Main = () => (
  <div>
    Testing Main Component
  </div>
);

export default Main;
```

I am confused because both App and Main are the same syntax but I can change the content of App to be the following and it renders to the screen with no issues:

```
import Main from './Main';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    This is a test render
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

I am kind of stuck and have read most of the other posts on SO with the same issue but none seem to help.  Sorry if this question should not be asked here but really stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

// Babel.js config

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx)?(\.erb)?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'add-module-exports', 'transform-react-inline-elements'],
    presets: [
      'react',
      'stage-2',
      'es2015',
      ['env', { modules: false }],
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Are you using Babel to transpile it to ES5 so IE can understand it?

Comment: does it load in google chrome but not IE9? If it does then that means you are compiling to ES6 instead of ES5. IE9 doesn't support ES6

Comment: Also, in `Main.jsx` are you importing `React` explicitly from `"react"`?

Comment: @AndrewLi yep. I am. As mentioned above if I just put plain text inside of the app component it renders. It only errors out when I try to remember the 'Main' component. Strange.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I am using babel to transpile the code. It works up until the main component render. If I remove that and render plain text it works.

Comment: Ok but where are you testing? only IE9? or is it all browsers? can you post your babel configurations?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I am testing in IE 9, chrome and Firefox.  I will post my babe config shortly.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I have added the config for babel which includes the stuff I am loading.

Comment: You did not `import React from 'react'` inside App

Comment: @WilomGfx Sorry, I missed that when I copy pasted.  I do indeed have that included.

Comment: Are you sure you included the correct import?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yep.  Definitely sure.  It works in all browsers except IE9 (have not tried 10 yet)  I also have other components that work fine.  Once I add my main component in it errors out.  Event when I just have 1 div and plain text inside that div.

Comment: Your webpack config is wrong unless you just cut parts of it out. It's not matching `.jsx`. Plus, use the ES2015 preset too.

Comment: @AndrewLi Updated to include the jsx extension as well as the ES2015 preset.  Still no joy!

Comment: Try `test: /\.jsx?$/,`

Comment: @AndrewLi Not sure if this makes sense but I tracked down the issue.  Any component that is using a return statement inside of the component render method throws the error in IE9!

Comment: @user28891 Incredibly weird. Maybe a transpile issue with Babel? If you find the source and if it's a bug, report it.

Comment: @AndrewLi I am about to dive in to babel / webpack setup now! Wish me luck and thanks for helping out, appreciate it!